# cant get upstart script for node.js program to start on startup

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, node.js

I made a rather simple startup script for my node.js program that should run on startup:

```
start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
    exec sudo -u max WEBSITES_DIR=/home/max/websites/ /usr/local/bin/node /home/max/websites/server.js 2>&1 >> /var/log/node.log
end script
```

If I use:

```
sudo start my-program
```

it works, but when I reboot the machine I get the error message:

```
init: my-program main process (325) terminated with status 2
```

Anybody any idea on how to debug this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `startup` event is the very first event that gets emitted in the Upstart bootup process. There are all kinds of things that won't have happened yet - the root filesystem will still be mounted read-only, networking hasn't been initialized, etc.

I suspect that the job is exiting quickly because all of its dependencies (explicit or implicit) aren't initialized yet. I'd change the start condition to something like

```
start on filesystem and started networking
```

At least then you'll be able to write to your logfile.

As a side note, it looks like you reversed your output redirection arguments - you actually meant `>> /var/log/node.log 2>&1`. Using `2>&1` means "take whatever is currently fd 1, and make fd 2 the same thing", but you haven't changed what stdout is yet.

Comment: Thats a good hint, thanks! Will try it out tomorrow. The script I am executing is on a mounted drive (the server is a virtual machine on my development pc) – is that already mounted when the filesystem is ready? Thanks a lot for the note on the redirection arguments. :-)

Comment: The "filesystem" event is emitted when all filesystems listed in `/etc/fstab` (and also `/lib/init/fstab`) have been mounted.

There are also events emitted for each filesystem, and certain classes of filesystem.

The upstart-events(7) manpage has more information about the different standard events. It's new in Natty, so if you don't have that, you can read it with crappy formatting at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man7/upstart-events.7.html

Comment: In case anyone comes across this question from a virtual machine environment such as vagrant, use `start on virtual-filesystems`. This will wait for things like network mounts. (Ref: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/virtual-filesystems.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

HiMax,

Startup node.js on Ubuntu server

`more /etc/init/noded.conf`

Ubuntu upstart file at `/etc/init/noded.conf`:

```
description "noded.conf"

author      "ntbinh"

start on runlevel [2345]

stop on runlevel [06]

respawn

script

su - ubuntu -c "NODE_ENV=test exec sudo /etc/init.d/noded start"

end script
```

You have already `/etc/init.d/noded`. You can edit `/etc/init/noded.conf`  ==> startup booting:

```
 # Ubuntu upstart file at `/etc/init/noded.conf`


 description "noded.conf"
 author      "ntbinh"

 respawn

 start on runlevel [2345]

 stop on runlevel [06]

 script

 su - ubuntu -c "NODE_ENV=test exec sudo /usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/node /home/ubuntu/server.js" >> /home/ubuntu/log.log 

 end script
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the similar error was caused by trying to start a script from my upstart script, that didn't actually exist. It turned out that I forgot to commit and push the script.